# Android unified photo quality

Tags: android, android-camera, camera-calibration

I am using android camera API to take pictures. But I know very little about cameras and taking pictures in general, so I am having quite a hard time. Currenly I am able to take pictures, but the quality differes on different devices.

That is a sample from one device[image: sample1]

And there is the same scene from second device[image: sample2]

So my question is what parameters of camera object should I set to get the same results on every device when the lighting conditions are identical?

Comment: Camera hardware differs greatly in quality and capability. You are not going to get the same results from different devices.

Comment: Ok, that is resonable. But I have noticed that those two pictures have very different exposure times. Isn't it affecting the quality like a lot?

Comment: As far as I know there is no single magic exposure time which provides optimum results for all cameras and for all possible photo subjects. There are ~24,000 Android device models, so my guess is that you will not be able to test them all. That is why fancier camera apps allow users to adjust camera settings, so they can tune the app based on the results that they are getting from their camera.

Comment: You are right. So what parameters whould you recommend to adjust to close the brightness gap between those photos? What about ISO and exposure?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify some parameters for taking a photo, but since every device has different camera characteristics you should first check and apply your settings accordingly. For these specifications yo can look to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics)  . Do not forget every device has  different camera and you cannot be sure that every photo taken by different devices will be the same. However you can apply some image transformations or filtering for getting same kind of images (ex: grayscale).
Also i suggest you to look more deeply on [Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) of the android for more detailed information.

Comment: Using Camera2 API is unfortunately not an option right now. 
Maybe I was a little to radical in my question. Those photos don't really have to be exacly the same. I just want to know what parameters to set to reduce this huge gap between them.

Comment: If you are gonna use deprecated api then it has similar features as well take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters and you can specify like enabling auto white balance etc.